# How to Delete the row using NOT IN from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to use multiple `NOT IN` in sql

```
DELETE FROM courses
    WHERE course_id
        NOT IN
        (SELECT course_id FROM enrollment)
        AND course_id = $id
```

Some of the method i tried

```
DELETE FROM courses
    WHERE course_id
        NOT IN
        ((SELECT course_id FROM enrollment) || (SELECT courseid FROM fees))
        AND course_id = $id  

DELETE FROM courses
    WHERE course_id
        NOT IN (SELECT course_id FROM enrollment)
        OR 
        NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM fees)
        AND course_id = $id

DELETE FROM courses
    WHERE course_id
        NOT IN
        (SELECT course_id FROM enrollment WHERE course_id = $id
        UNION
        SELECT courseid FROM fees WHERE courseid = $id)
```

Comment: Is there any error message involved in using some of the queries you've tried?

Comment: No errors. but the row did not get deleted.

Comment: What's wrong with WHERE course_id NOT IN (...) AND course_id NOT IN (...)

Comment: Tried. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work just fine:

```
DELETE FROM courses
WHERE course_id NOT IN (SELECT course_id FROM enrollment)
  AND course_id NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM fees)
  AND course_id = $id
```

If it's still not working for you I suggest changing **DELETE** to **SELECT course_id** and add/remove conditions one by one until you understand what is happening in your query.

Also long as you want to use **OR**s and **AND**s in a single query it's advised to use brackets so it's easier to read the order in which conditions are checked.

Comment: Works. Great. Thanks!